# How can I find “documentary evidence” for App Store Approval, When content of the application is my Idea

Tags: ios, iphone

this is what they sent me :

//========================== Email

Hello,

Thank you again for your reply

We understand your app is implementing customized content and is not duplicating Dead Space. However, your app is creating a close resemblance to Dean Space, which is a copyrighted content.

Please refer to our previous correspondence for details about your app’s rejection. Please revise your app to ensure it is compliant with the App Store Review Guidelines prior to resubmitting it for review

You may attach documentary evidence in the App Review Information section in App Store Connect. In accordance with section 3.2(f) of the Apple Developer Program License Agreement, you acknowledge that submitting falsified or fraudulent documentation can result in the termination of your Apple Developer Program account and the removal of your apps from the App Store. Once Legal has reviewed your documentation and confirms its validity, we will proceed with the review of your app.

Best regards,

App Store Review

How can I get documentary evidence when my application is my design my idea even if the voice of character is my voice.

Thank you

Comment: this is an image https://image.ibb.co/f5UdD9/IMG_3889.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I pass the appeal from apple and getting approve (Waiting for 2 weeks)
I also send right evidence which create on my own with legal link